# naming threads, using typedef/struct

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am creating a program to practice using threads. I am trying to name them so that when the program is run, you can clearly see "Flight 1 is taking off..." or "Flight 6 is landing..." and so on. I would like every thread to have a flyTime (so I know what order they will use the runway in) which will be randomly generated. I have tried and am having difficulty using struct/typedef to give each pthread these characteristics so i can say for example flight.flyTime and use it throughout the program. Here is the relevant part of my code without my landing/takeoff functions:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

#define NUM_THREADS     8               //8 flights

pthread_mutex_t runway1lock;

void *FlightID(void *flightid){
    long fid;
    fid = (long)flightid;
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

typedef struct{                 //each plane has these characteristics
    long fid;
    int StartState;        // if start=1 ==> taking off:::if start=2 ==> landing
    int flyTime;           //fly == randomly generated time (order)
}FLIGHTS;

FLIGHTS flights[NUM_THREADS];

int StartState(flights[NUM_THREADS]){
    int startState;
    for (int i=0; i<=NUM_THREADS; i++){
           startState = rand() % 1+2;
    }
    std::string start;
    if(startState == 1){
            start = "Taking off";
    }
    if(startState == 2){
            start = "Landing";
    }
    for (int t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++){
            std::cout << "Start State for Flight# " << FlightID << " is " << start << std::endl;
    }
    return startState;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
//  pthread_t flights[NUM_THREADS];   //pthread_t keeps a thread ID after the thread is created with pthread_create()
                                    //it's like an index on a vector of threads
    int rc;
    long t;
    for (t=1; t<=NUM_THREADS; t++){          //loop creates threads(flights)
            printf("In main: Creating flight %1d\n", t);
            rc = pthread_create(&flights[t], NULL, FlightID, (void *)t);
            if (rc){
                    printf("ERROR: return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
                    return (-1);
            }
            printf("Created flight %1d\n", t);
            StartState(flights[t]);           //gives every flight a start state
            if(StartState(flights[t])==1){
                    std::cout << "Flight # " << &flights[t] << " is listed as waiting at the gate." << std::endl;
                    //go to takeoff function and go through switch case     
            }
            if(StartState(flights[t])==2){`enter code here`
                    std::cout << "Flight # " << &flights[t] << " is listed as waiting to land." << std::endl;
                    //go to landing function and go through switch case     
            }
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: why don't you use C++ threads? Your code looks very much like C with some C++ extensions ...

Comment: To be honest I'm not familiar with C or C++ so I wouldn't be sure how to use threads any differently than above. I can successfully print out "Creating flight 1, Created flight 1, creating flight 2, created flight 2" and so on, but that uses %1d -- when I get down to the use of FlightID... "Flight #1 is listed as waiting to land" prints several times, which means FlightID didn't get assigned to each thread (rather than &flights[t]) as I had intended it to

Comment: it's still unclear what you're actually trying to achieve. Perhaps you can generate a SSCCE?

Answer (score 0):

There is a code snippet below that represents how I would implement it.

You should also take a look at **pthread_key_create**, **pthread_getspecific** and **pthread_setspecific**. This is a set of functions that allow you to have data, specific to each thread, stored in the thread's memory context. It may come in handy for in your code, later on.

```
typedef struct{
    long fid;
    int StartState;
    int flyTime;
} FLIGHTS;

FLIGHTS** flights = new FLIGHTS*[NUM_THREADS];
pthread_key_t pkey:

void *FlightID(void *flightid){
    long fid;
    fid = (long)flightid;
    FLIGHTS* flight = new FLIGHTS();
    flight->fid = fid;
    flights[fid] = flight;
    pthread_setspecific(pkey, flight);

    int startState;
    for (int i=0; i<=NUM_THREADS; i++){
           startState = rand() % 1+2;
    }
    std::string start;
    if(startState == 1){
            start = "Taking off";
    }
    if(startState == 2){
            start = "Landing";
    }
    for (int t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++){
            std::cout << "Start State for Flight# " << fid << " is " << start << std::endl;
    }

    flight->StartState = startState;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    pthread_key_create(&pkey, NULL);
    for (t=1; t<=NUM_THREADS; t++){
        rc = pthread_create(&flights[t], NULL, FlightID, (void *)t);
        if (rc){
            printf("ERROR: return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
            return (-1);
        }
        printf("Created flight %1d\n", t);
    }
}
```

Also, I don't know if I'm understanding your code correctly or if you just have some coding errors on it, so I leave you with some questions or remarks that could be mistakes/bugs:

1) You invoke pthread_exit in the start callback function:

```
void *FlightID(void *flightid){
    long fid;
    fid = (long)flightid;
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

2) You pass to the **<<** operator a function with no return value:

```
    std::cout << "Start State for Flight# " << FlightID << " is " << start << std::endl;
```

3) You invoke the same function 3 times just to get the return value. Shouldn't it be *int state = StartState(flights[i])* and then test the *state* variable value?
StartState(flights[t]);           //gives every flight a start state

```
    if(StartState(flights[t])==1){
            std::cout << "Flight # " << &flights[t] << " is listed as waiting at the gate." << std::endl;
            //go to takeoff function and go through switch case     
    }
    if(StartState(flights[t])==2){`enter code here`
            std::cout << "Flight # " << &flights[t] << " is listed as waiting to land." << std::endl;
            //go to landing function and go through switch case     
    }
```

4) You can't define a function like this:

```
int StartState(flights[NUM_THREADS]){
```